# State not updated when accessing Component directly in React Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I have an app with a table and a Reducer class is connected to it:

```
const ProjectsList = (props) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("Loading projects");
        props.getProjects();
    }, []);

    const {projects} = props.projects;

    const items = projects.map(project => {
        return <Project key={project.id} project={project}/>;
    });

    return (
        <Main open={props.drawer}>
            <DrawerHeader/>
            <TableContainer>
                <Table sx={{minWidth: 650}} aria-label="Projects Table">
                    <TableHead>
                        <TableRow>
                            <TableCell>Name</TableCell>
                            <TableCell align="right">Created at</TableCell>
                            <TableCell align="right">Added by</TableCell>
                            <TableCell align="right">Actions</TableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                    </TableHead>
                    <TableBody>
                        {items}
                    </TableBody>
                </Table>
            </TableContainer>
        </Main>
    );
}

ProjectsList.propTypes = {
    getProjects: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    projects: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    projects: state.projects
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
    getProjects
})(withRouter(ProjectsList));
```

Reducer (relevant part):

```
const initialState = {
    projects: []
};

export const projectsReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_PROJECTS:
            return {
                ...state,
                projects: action.payload
            };
```

When I navigate from another page this Component loads correctly (the useEffect hook runs, loads items from API), but when I try to access it directly (with its direct URL) or when anything changes on this page and the page gets re-rendered (eg.: props.drawer changes), the state is lost.

I want the state to be loaded every time from the store and it should refresh when the whole page gets refreshed.

Comment: Can you clarify what "when I try to access it directly (with its direct URL)" means? The effect has an empty dependency, so it only runs when the component mounts. You could add a dependency to retrigger the effect, though it's not clear what any dependency could be.

Comment: Sure and thanks for your help! So this page live under a '/projects'. When I open the page '/' another Component gets loaded. If I navigate from the Drawer menu to this page, it loads perfectly. If I open this url directly 'http://domain/projects' the projects are not loaded, though I can see that the useEffect runs (when the component mounts).

Comment: I'm not sure if this is related to your problem, but I think your destructure should be `const { projects } = props;`.

Comment: @JeremyKlukan Unfortunately no. The interesting part is, that from what I see the logic is correct. Anytime the data should load, I can see from console output that the query ran and I get a valid answer, but somehow it is not always dispatched

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem and the actual solution was not related to my question.
The problem was with the `useMediaQuery` function in `@mui`.

It re-rendered the whole page twice, that's why it was like the state is not updated.
If I accessed it not directly, the main component was already loaded (where the `useMediaQuery` was placed) and that's why it worked in that way.

[Redux state not dispatched on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70147095/redux-state-not-dispatched-on-page-load)